# How do I write a public function to return a head pointer of a linked list?

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

```
class Newstring
{
public:
    Newstring();
    void inputChar ( char);
    void display ();
    int length ();
    void concatenate (char);
    void concatenate (Newstring);
    bool substring (Newstring);
    void createList ();
    Node * getHead (); // error
private:
    struct Node
    {
        char item;
        Node *next; 
    };
    Node *head;

};
```

I am getting a **syntax error : missing ';' before '*'** on the declaration for my getHead function (yes I can't think of a better name).  The purpose of this function is to return the head pointer.

Comment: Ok I got it.  I just swapped the private and public blocks around.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: Note that you can have multiple private/protected/public blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare Node before you use it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare the Node struct above getHead();

```
class Newstring
{

public:
    struct Node
    {
        char item;
        Node *next; 
    };
    Newstring();
    void inputChar ( char);
    void display ();
    int length ();
    void concatenate (char);
    void concatenate (Newstring);
    bool substring (Newstring);
    void createList ();
    Node * getHead (); // error
private:

    Node *head;

};
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it by keeping the struct private?

Comment: Brandon> you can just declare the structure, added an answer to show how.

Answer (score 2):

To answer Brandon about keeping the struct in private, or keeping the current code while adding a declaration, the way is :

```
class Newstring
{
    struct Node; // here the declaration
public:

    Newstring();
    void inputChar ( char);
    void display ();
    int length ();
    void concatenate (char);
    void concatenate (Newstring);
    bool substring (Newstring);
    void createList ();
    Node * getHead (); // error
private:
    struct Node
    {
        char item;
        Node *next; 
    };
    Node *head;

};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Node * getHead()
```

Compiler is not able to get the definition of `Node` when getHead() is encountered.

```
  struct Node
    {
        char item;
        Node *next; 
    };
```

Put the definition of Node before it is used.

```
class Newstring
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        char item;
        Node *next; 
    };
    Node *head;
public:
    Newstring(); ...
    Node * getHead ();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to forward declare `Node` by placing a `struct` before `Node`

```
    :
    void createList ();
    struct Node * getHead ();
private:
    struct Node
    {
        :
```